# Understanding the behavior of HypergeometricPFQ

Tags: divergent-series, hypergeometric-function

I am using HypergeometricPFQ functions (more exactly $_3F_2$) as approximants for other more complicated functions. Here are three of them (corresponding to N=3, N=4 and N=5, respectively, in the plots below):

```
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1., -11.359073074960966, -0.9496684005505038}, {-11.842171437570526, -0.6544878051911667}, - \[Tau]]

    HypergeometricPFQ[{1., -0.993892734328931, -0.052722890162238745}, {-0.9519055083936611, -0.02621386350907018}, - \[Tau]]   

    HypergeometricPFQ[{1., -1.0042388354011744, 0.22226474916891914}, {-1.0459210550826585, 0.07845826690277335}, - \[Tau]]
```

A plot of the functions above in terms of $\tau$ shows that the very first HypergeometricPFQ shown above (the $N=3$ case) goes to a very large negative value when $\tau$ increases while the other ones do not
show this type of behavior:
[plot of HypergeometricPFQ with all cases, the N=3 case decreases much faster than the other ones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Btd7.png)

Removing the $N = 3$ case it is possible get a better visualization of the other functions. They all decrease with $\tau$ as well but much slower than the problematic case.
[Same plot as above, without the N=3 case for better presentation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZzyp.png)

I am using the Mathematica software to make these calculations/plots. I am aware that sometimes the default precision is not good to get results with some special functions, but I already took care of that and checked this plot with a large working precision.

At the end of the day I would Laplace transform
these functions and end up having Meijer-G functions, which
are more complicated and would still show this behavior of
diverging to minus infinity as well (I already checked that this
is the case for the first HypergeometricPFQ above).

I already read topics and searched on forums
about hypergeometric functions but I failed to understand what
exactly causes the first HypergeometricPFQ to sort of diverge to
minus infinity when $\tau$ increases. My guess is that it has
something to do with large values of the parameters (i.e. -11.842171437570526 and -11.359073074960966) but I was not able to go much further than this.
I already checked that the ratio of the coefficients in the series that defines HypergeometricPFQ go to 1 (because this is a $_pF_q$ where $p=q+1$).

I know $_3F_2(a_1, a_2, a_3; b_1, b_2; -\tau)$ has an infinite number of poles as a function of $b_1$ and $b_2$. My understanding was that after fixing $b_1$ and $b_2$ to a value that is not a pole, the function would have a smooth behavior with respect to $\tau$, which is not the case for $N=3$. So, I do not know exactly what causes this behavior in the $N=3$ case.

I really appreciate any help, references, etc...

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! I'm somewhat unclear about your main question. Is it "Why does the first HypergeometricPFQ diverge to minus infinity when  increases?"

Comment: Hello, thank you. Yes, I would like to understand this ("Why does the first HypergeometricPFQ diverge to minus infinity when  increases?). More specifically what is the reason it goes to minus infinity for values of $\tau$ where the other HypergeometricPFQ are well behaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hypergeometric functions $_NF_{N-1}$, there exist connection formulas relating their behavior at $0$ and $\infty$, such as these: [1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8.E8), [2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8#E7) (for generic parameters).

Looking at the asymptotics of the r.h.s. as $z\to-\infty$, you may see that
$_NF_{N-1}\left(\begin{array}{c} a_1,\ldots a_N \\ b_1,\ldots b_{N-1}\end{array};z\right)$
behaves, up to an explicitly known constant prefactor, as $(-z)^{\max_{k}\{-a_k\}}$. Thus it is the value $a_2=-11.35907$ which is responsible for faster divergence. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this question, I appreciate it! I did get to the same answer you gave but was not able to update this post sooner. The combination of parameters (for divergent case, $N=3$) is such that the coefficients in front of each $(-z)^{a_k}$ term (since it is a $_3F_2$ we get three terms of type $(-z)^{a_k}$) are very large (along with the dominant $sim -z^{11}$ behavior). I verified that the reason those coefficients are large (like $\sim 10^{14} - 10^{15}$ (if my memory does not fail) is because they are close to poles of Gamma functions.